# Crossed Vs nested factors in clinical study design

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, nested-data, cross-section

I'm conducting a clinical survey which has a really complex experimental design and I have doubts about what factors need to be considered as nested and which crossed. The study include 30 subjects, 15 with colorectal cancer (CRC) and 15 healthy controls. In the two groups 5 subjects were not treated whereas 5 were treated with prebiotics, and the remaining 5 with probiotics. Microbiological data were collected from 3 different district (biopsy, stool, and saliva) for each subject at 4 different time points (0, 3, 6, and 12 month).

As far as I know, districts should be considered nested within subjects since two samples coming from different patients are not equal to each other. Time points are indeed crossed with district, subjects and treatments that are in turn crossed with districts. In principle treatments are nested within subjects since patients received only a single treatment. For the same reason, also the status (CRC VS healthy) is nested within subjects since a subject can be only healthy or affected by CRC and, for extension, even the districts are nested within statuses.

I'm interested in how microbial data change over time in different districts but I'm also interested in how the treatment may affect these changes in CRC and healthy subjects. I was planning to use subjects as random factor in a model that I would represent like this (I will call microbiological data `y` since I think the discussion about the kind of data is out of scope):

`y ~ (district + treatment + status)*time + (1|subjects)`

What are your thoughts? Does the model seem to represent my data correctly?